# ld.so.conf does not get loaded by ldconfig

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking

So I've edited my `/etc/ld.so.conf` file and now it looks like this:

```
include /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64_lin
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
include /usr/local/lib
```

I've tried running `sudo ldconfig -v`, but in the output it does not seem to even attempt to load the MKL library directory. When I try to run a program using MKL it fails. However, if I add a symbolic link to the correct library in `/usr/local/lib` which gets added from `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf` it works. Obviously this is an easy solution, but I'm trying to understand why my `ldconfig` fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add library or directory itself:

`/full/Path/to/library.so/or/directory` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` file

*You must remove **include** word before directory in your config file.*

From `man ldconfig`:

> The ldconfig utility is used to prepare a set of ``hints'' for use
>   by the
>        dynamic linker to facilitate quick lookup of shared libraries available
>        in multiple directories.
>   <...>
>
> Files named on the command line are expected to contain directories to
>        scan for shared libraries.  Each directory's pathname must start on a new
>        line.  Blank lines and lines starting with the comment character `#' are
>        ignored.  Filenames must conform to the lib*.so.[0-9] pattern in order to
>        be added to the hints file.

Comment: So you mean I have to add instead `/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_rt.so`  for instance?